# What are Firebase Realtime Database billing policy for data download into GCP? #AskFirebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

#### TL; DR

What is Firebase Realtime Database general network pricing GCP egress traffic (i.e. data downloaded from Firebase to GCP?

#### Description

For requests that originate within Google Cloud Platform (for example, from an application running on Google Compute Engine), [Firebase Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#general_network_pricing) apps are charged as follows:

- Free

  - Ingress
  - Egress within a region
  - Egress between regions in the same multi-region
- Billed

  - [Egress between regions within the US (per GiB)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#general_network_pricing)
  - [Egress between regions, not including traffic between US regions](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing#internet-egress)

Does Firebase realtime database ignores egress traffic to GCP instances or is it billed a usual downloads?

However Firebase Realtime Database data [download billing rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing) are limited to:

> **Data downloaded:** When clients get data from your database, Firebase
>   charges for the downloaded data. Typically, this makes up the bulk of
>   your bandwidth costs, but it isn't the only factor in your bill.

Should Firestore egress rules be the same to Firebase? Or should the traffic be billed as any common download?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database charges for all outbound traffic, no matter its destination. There is no free egress traffic for Realtime Database.

Comment: That explains why the console is charging the downloaded data. It would be really nice for GCP partners if egress no-billing feature was also extended to FRB.

Comment: Agreed. Consider [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to add your vote to that.

Comment: CASE 00010802: Free egress traffic from Realtime Database to GCP